# Parse в SimpleDateFormat возвращает правильное время, но первое число года

Tags: java, парсер, дата, simpledateformat

Есть строка вида `"2018-04-04-16-20-38"` в переменной `arg[2]`
Есть `SimpleDateFormat MY_SIMPLEDATEFORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss");`
И кусок кода, который работает не так, как ожидаю:

```
try {
    Date date = new Date(); 
    // fastTime 1523004108(172) = 06.04.2018 @ 11:41:48
    date = MY_SIMPLEDATEFORMAT.parse(arg[2]);
    // fastTime 1514812838(000) = 01.01.2018 @ 16:20:38 - первое число года
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Добавил для проверки:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd");
Date d = sdf.parse(arg[2]); //"2018-04-04-16-20-38"
// fastTime 1514812838(000) = 01.01.2018 @ 00:00:00 - тоже первое число года
// с ожидаемым 0 часов 0 минут.
```

Подскажите, в чем проблема, и почему неправильно парсится `2018-04-04`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Замените `YYYY` на `yyyy`.

```
SimpleDateFormat MY_SIMPLEDATEFORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss");
```

Согласно документации [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) заглавная `Y` означает «week year» — год, который отсчитывается с начала первой недели, а не с 1-го января.

> Y | Week year

При этом в документации не упоминается (либо я не нашел), что если в дате указывается «недельный» год, то при парсинге вся дата считается «недельной» и ожидается, что будут указаны номер недели в году (`w`) и день недели (`u`). Это неявно видно из примеров использования:

> `YYYY-'W'ww-u"`
>   `2001-W27-3`

Если номер недели в году (`w`) и день недели (`u`) не указаны, то они считаются равными 1. Параметры день недели (`dd`) и день месяца (`MM`) в «недельной» дате игнорируются, соответственно возвращается первый понедельник первого дня недели, входящей в год.

2018‑й год начался с понедельника, поэтому дата выпадает на 1‑е января. Для 2017‑го получилось бы по‑другому:

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss");
 Date d = sdf.parse("2017-04-04-16-20-38");
 //26-12-2016
 System.out.printf("%1$td-%1$tm-%1$tY", d);
```

**Дополнение:** Изучение исходного кода показало, что определение «недельного» года прописано во внутреннем классе `java.text.CalendarBuilder`, а именно в методе [`establish`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/text/CalendarBuilder.java#l103), который вызывается в конце парсинга в `SimpleDateFormat`.

```
 boolean weekDate = isSet(WEEK_YEAR)
                        && field[WEEK_YEAR] > field[YEAR];
 ...
 if (weekDate) {
     //считает по особенному
```

Т.о. дата считается «недельной» если в строке формата:

- указан `Y` и не указан `y`;
- либо указаны оба варианта, но `Y` идет последним.

Answer (score 2):

Можете попробовать так:

```
    public class DateHelp {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss");
            try {
                Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse("2018-04-04-16-20-38");
                System.out.println(date);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Вывод:
Wed Apr 04 16:20:38 MSK 2018